# pass data to included file not working(php)

Tags: php, templates, scope

on my sample mvc project i have a render function that include the view file 
and sometimes in my controller i want to pass success or error massage to view forms(from controller)
render function:

```
  public function render($view)
{
    include 'view/'.$view.'.php';
}
```

controller:

```
   public function sendguide()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $success='ur massage posted successfully '; 
        $this->render('sendguide');
    }
    else
    $this->render('sendguide');
}
```

and this is the part of view that i print success message in:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right"> &nbsp
    <input  name='submit' type='submit' value='ثبت دزخواست'  ><?php echo $success; ?>

    </tr>
```

it seems when i set `$success` and sent it to my view the view have to print
success message but it didnt work!

what's i'm missing?
tnx

Comment: The issue seems to be that message is set to ``$success`` , then ``render`` function is getting called which will include the view file. But ``$success`` message is not getting passed to view.

Comment: @SameerK  i think when i include one file php (or maby apache?) get a copy of that file in my current file and u can imagine that i have my view file that on top of that i initialize `$success` is'nt this true ?

Comment: @MR.masoud, your function `render` works in its own scope. It doesn't know anything about outer variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables from the current script will be accessible in an included file (providing they are assigned before the include).

However in your example, the `$success` variable is not accessible in the your `render()` function and therefore not available to the script you include from the function.

The PHP documentation describes exactly your problem with variable scope;

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

You can pass the $success variable as a parameter to your render() function;

```
  public function render($view, $success='')
{
    include 'view/'.$view.'.php';
}
```

I added `$success=''` as a parameter. The `=''` means if no value is provided it will default to an empty string.

Pass `$success` to the function in the function call;

```
  public function sendguide()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $success='ur massage posted successfully '; 
        $this->render('sendguide', $success);
    }
    else
    $this->render('sendguide');
}
```

As a side note: I would assign `$success` a Boolean value (true/false) to pass to the function to define success or failure. Then in your view file you can check success: `if($success) echo...` an appropriate message to the user, rather than passing the message (String) around in the `$success` variable from your script.